# flask showing error in jsonify

Tags: python

I have a flask app and this line in one of my view is giving me error :

```
return flask.jsonify({'target_id':str(target_id+1), 'html':'<ul>\n{}\n</ul>'.format('\n'.join(f'<li>{i}</li>' for i in result))})
```

Error is shown in this part : `f'<li>{i}</li>' for i in result`

What is the issue?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, it runs just fine for me. What is the traceback? What version of python are you using?

Comment: It is giving me a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is nothing to do with Flask. You're using Python 3.4 but trying to use [`f` string formatting](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/?) which wasn't introduced until Python 3.6. You need to use instead:

```
return flask.jsonify({'target_id':str(target_id+1), 'html':'<ul>\n{}\n</ul>'.format('\n'.join('<li>{}</li>'.format(i) for i in result))})
```